# How to determine virtual registry hives?

Tags: c++, winapi, hive, registry

My problem is to determine if hive is virtual by WinAPI. Saying "virtual", I mean generated hives, while Windows was starting. I need to find out, what data stores on hard drive in files like `Windows/System32/config/SAM`, `Windows/System32/config/SECURITY` etc.

I search stackoverflow and google, but didn't find anything about it. Maybe, I just make wrong query. What shoud I search? Please, help.

Edit: maybe, someone know, how to find out if registry hive is reference to other.

Comment: Why do you think these are generated at boot? SAM contains local user account data and is certainly not generated at boot.

Comment: Ok, I need to find out, what hives will stored onto hard drive. For example, I can use hivex to parse this files from linux.

Answer (score 1):

The HKEY to hive file mappings are documented [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724877(v=vs.85).aspx).

All keys except keys created with the [`REG_OPTION_VOLATILE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724844(v=vs.85).aspx) option are saved in a hive file but I don't think there is a function you can call to get this file from a HKEY handle. There is no reason for Windows to provide an API to do this because the hive format is not documented.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I don't need to get file from HKEY, I need to get information if this data is stores in files on shutdown.

Comment: Non-volatile keys are saved when the system performs a clean shutdown (not a crash).